# Does scrapy have a end_url parameter?

Tags: python, parameters, scrapy

a new programmer here. Trying to figure out whether Scrapy has an end_url parameter just like it has a start_url parameter. I want to crawl a specific amount of items from a given website.

Is this possible? Or should I just use Crawl Rules

```
start_url=[""]
end_url=[""]
```

NB: I am new to using Scrapy and I have read their documentation. But I can't seem to figure this out.
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How would that "end_url" parameter behave? It's pretty clear how `start_url` operates; it's very much up to speculation how an "end_url" parameter should behave.

Comment: _"I want to crawl a specific amount of items from a given website."_: check [CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std:setting-CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT)

Comment: @deceze I was hoping to specifiy an end url in that parameter. Supposing I started with www.example.com/page/1/, Is there a way to end the crawl at www.example.com/page/2/

Comment: Since one webpage contains links to many other webpages, all of which may or may not eventually lead to your "end_url", or not, or may lead there in circles, this is rather nonsensical in itself. It's up to you to stop "finding" more links to crawl.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I hadn't come across that earlier. It seems like a viable solution, however, I really don't know how to incorporate that into my existing code. And posting that code for you to review would seem like am wasting your time.

Comment: I tried using parsedatetime library to scrape current items, but that solution didn't work. See my problem is trying to get the scraper to get items posted in a day.

Comment: You may want to ask another question, describing your use-case, sample spider code (with what you tried) and results you got, and explaining what you expected instead.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I asked this a while ago. Here's the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062484/using-scrapy-to-crawl-latest-questions . Is it possible for you guys to look it over and tell me what am missing here, please.